# JWT-based authorization in microservice architecture with dedicated identity service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have two services implemented as Web APIs in ASP.NET Core, dockerized and orchestrated (docker-compose and Kubernetes). One service provides authentication and authorization (authNZ, `IdentityService`), and the other provides resources to authNZ'd users (`ResourceService`).

Any authenticated user (OIDC-based authentication against Google) has a JWT token, which they can use to add as a `bearer` token to their API calls to the `ResourceService`.

**Q1**: Should `ResourceService` validate every token calling `IdentityService`?

Supposing the answer is *yes*, the authorization middleware of the `ResourceService` fails with the following error when validating authNZ to an API endpoint.

> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
>
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
>
> Exception occurred while processing message.
> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

**Q2**: Do I need to implement the `.well-known` endpoints in the `IdentityService` to validate the JWT tokens?

*I am aware of the complexities and challenges associated with implementing an Identity service without leveraging dedicated libraries (e.g., IdentityServer4). However, given some licensing issues, I cannot leverage such libraries.*

I am sharing some setups I find most relevant, but happy to share other parts of the code if needed.

- AuthNZ configuration of the `ResourceService`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://identity";
    options.Audience = "https://resource";
});
```

- AuthNZ configuration of the `IdentityService`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options => 
{
    options.Authority = "https://identity";
    options.Audience = "https://resource";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/api/v1/authnz/signin";
})
.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "...";
    options.ClientSecret = "...";
    options.CallbackPath = "/authnz/google/callback";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Clients and APIs needs to be able to download the configuration document at https://identity/.well-known/openid-configuration and it should be a public document that is not protected in anyway.

When you get this error:

> Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from

It is typically because the service can't reach the IdentityProvider. Typically it s a HTTPS or networking issue in your backend.

Every service that provides tokens should preferably expose a configuration document. If you are using IdentityServer, this is built-in.

The alternative is that you provide the public signing key manually to each service.

To fix Q1, the it all depends on the deployment and network setup of your services. It is typically either due to HTTPS certificate issues or if one service can't talk to other services behind the firewall. Sometimes you might need to use a different "service name" when you need to send HTTP(s) requests behind the firewall.

Comment: Ideally, I want to minimize traffic to the `IdentityService`. So, given tokens are only used in the API gateway, is it a good practice to share the `SymmetricSecurityKey` between the `IdentityService` and the gateway so that gateway can validate tokens without consulting with the `IdentityService`?

Comment: Also, is there any dotnet feature to implement the `.well-known` endpoint? (I cannot use `IdentityServer4` due to recent changes in its licensing.)

Comment: Don't think there is a need to implement it all by yourself. There is always https://documentation.openiddict.com/ as an alternative to IdentityServer.

Comment: Any thoughts on Q1? Elaborated in the first comment here.